# HTML table cells are tiny and not showing array data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, html-table

I am new to using HTML and javascript and just playing around with a form and a table, i am looking to push data into the table and simply display it. I have this working as I can see from the console the system is logging the data and can see the extra cells being added to my table. However i'm getting a weird thing happening with my table, the cells are all tiny and the data does not show:

[HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVBsO.png)

I also have a small array of 4 items populating the table, hence why there are 4 rows populated.

Has anyone seen this before? am i missing something simple? (appreciate you may not know until seeing the code but may be something simple, i will attach more code snippets under this post)

I also am not sure what section of the code to attach to this post but here is what i have relating to the table style:

```js
function addTableRow(ProductCode, ProductName, ProductTotal, Price, Offer, LCOffer){
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName){
        return;
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("inventoryTable").rows.length;
    tableBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
    row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.id = x

    ProductCodeC = document.createElement("td");
    ProductNameC = document.createElement("td");
    ProductTotalC = document.createElement("td");
    PriceC = document.createElement("td");
    OfferC = document.createElement("td");
    LCOfferC = document.createElement("td");


    ProductCodeC.width = "500px";
    ProductCodeC.height = "500px";
    ProductNameC.width = "500px";
    ProductNameC.height = "500px";
    ProductTotalC.width = "500px";
    ProductTotalC.height = "500px";
    PriceC.width = "500px";
    PriceC.height = "500px";
    OfferC.width = "500px";
    OfferC.height = "500px";
    LCOfferC.width = "500px";
    LCOfferC.height = "500px";

    
    ProductCodeTNode = document.createTextNode(ProductCode);
    ProductNameTNode = document.createTextNode(ProductName);
    ProductTotalTNode = document.createTextNode(ProductTotal);
    PriceTNode = document.createTextNode(Price);
    OfferTNode = document.createTextNode(Offer);
    LCOfferTNode = document.createTextNode(LCOffer);

    row.appendChild(ProductCodeC);
    row.appendChild(ProductNameC);
    row.appendChild(ProductTotalC);
    row.appendChild(PriceC);
    row.appendChild(OfferC);
    row.appendChild(LCOfferC);

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
    console.log(ProductName);
    console.log(ProductTotal)
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
      border: 2px solid white;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      color: black;
      width:auto;
      height:auto
      
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <table class="Inventory" id="inventoryTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Total</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Offer</th>
            <th>Loyalty card Offer</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: *"I also am not sure what section of the code to attach to this post"* - The table.  Please edit the question to include a runnable code snippet containing a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  If it's purely a styling issue then all you need is the HTML being rendered and the CSS which styles it.

Comment: thank you for your time @David, I have edited the post and included the snippets, if this is not enough please let me know. Appreciate your time

Comment: The code shown doesn't demonstrate the problem observed.  The table has no rows, save for the header row (and the yellow text on a white background is unnecessarily difficult to see), nothing ever calls the JavaScript function, etc.  Now would also be a good time for you to do some debugging and narrow down the problem.  Is the problem that the CSS styling doesn't look right?  Is the problem that the data isn't being inserted into the table?  Something else?  Your browser's debugging tools can help you with this.

Comment: apologies for missing out information, the javascript is called when the window loads, i have used window.onload for this and when i do run it, the 4 rows appear. If i remove an item from my array and save, the table then shows 3, when i add items to the table more rows appear but never any data. However when i use console.log i can see that the data is there. Does this sound like a CSS styling issue? what is missing form the above that you would need to see?

Comment: I have also made small changes with the CSS and html and can't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

This answer will probably be downvoted very quickly and your question will probably be closed because it "doesn't follow the rules" but maybe you can do small steps first and ascertain that your CSS is actually respected by your page and then build on that - step by step. The following snippet demonstrates that the height attribute *is* actually obeyed, also on completely empty `<td>`s:

```js
const data=[["1234-01","object1",7,23.98,34.99,"no"],["3321-02","object2",3,7.56,14.99,"yes"]];

document.querySelector("table").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",data.map(a=>`<tr><td>${a.join("</td><td>")}</td></tr>`).join(""));
```

```css
td {border:1px solid gray;
    height:50px;min-width:100px;}
```

```html
<div>
<table class="Inventory" id="inventoryTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Product Total</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Offer</th>
        <th>Loyalty card Offer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Further hint: you can make life easier for yourself, if you use something like `element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", table-row-html-string )` on the `<table>` DOM element instead of creating and modifying a lot of elements and nodes manually.